# Uninstall/upgrade tensorflow failed: __init__.cpython-35.pyc not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I previously installed tensorflow-gpu 0.12.0rc0 with Winpython-3.5.2, and when I tried to upgrade or uninstall it to install the newer version using both the Winpython Control Panel and pip, I got the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
'c:\\users\\moliang\\downloads\\winpython-64bit-3.5.2.3qt5\\python-3.5.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\session_bundle\\testdata\\saved_model_half_plus_two\\variables\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-35.pyc'`

I installed the tensorflow-gpu 0.12.0rc0 through Winpython-3.5.2 pip, and the `__init__.cpython-35.pyc` does exist at the correct directory. So I don't understand how this error could happen? And it prevents me from getting the new version.

Comment: I forced to delete the package in the python/lib/site-packages/ and reinstalled the tensorflow-gpu, and it seems working well. Though I solve this problem via such alternate I would still like to know the correct way to handle this...

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own answer (alternative) here in case someone overlooked comment:

I forced to delete the package in the `python/lib/site-packages/` and reinstalled the `tensorflow-gpu`, and it seems working well.

Though I solve this problem via such alternate I would still like to know the root cause and long-term fix for this.